# View time elapsed in foobar2000

Tags: foobar2000

I am using foobar2000 music player. How can display the **time elapsed** of currently playing song?

Answer (score 7):

CLick on `File` -> `Preferences`.

Expand Display -> Default User Interface. Under status bar add `%playback_time_remaining%` to whichever position you want.

This is how mine looks:

[image: Foobar]

The status bar code:

```
%codec% | %bitrate% kbps | %samplerate% Hz | %channels% | %playback_time% / [-%playback_time_remaining% / %length%]
```

Comment: I tried to use `%playback_time%` in `Display → Default User Interface → Playlist View → Custom columns`: it displays '?' sign in playlist. `%playback_time_remaining%` and `%played_length%`  are not working as well. Foobar 1.1.7. Ideas?

Comment: @dma_k if the length of the song is not available, both will not work. Try for few other songs

Comment: It turned out to be `%_length%` macro. Damn, it's difficult to find right solution in Google, as each reference lead to different solution, which depends on something I can't understand (FooBar version? module? moon phase?)

Comment: The dynamic values (as playback time) are not available in columns, nor in tray icon notification balloon.